# thread "main" java.lang.Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception 0

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to sorting a double array.An odd element should ascending order.An even element should descending.My classes is as follow.
When I runned project I show

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
package com.fatih.sortarray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SortingArray {

public static Double[] sortItOut(Double[] array) {

    Double[] arrayOdd = {};
    Double[] arrayEven = {};
    Double[] sortedArray = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;

        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            arrayOdd[k] = array[i];
            k++;
        } else {
            arrayEven[j] = array[i];
            j++;
        }

    }

    Arrays.sort(arrayOdd, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(arrayEven);

    List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrayOdd));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayEven));
    sortedArray = (Double[]) list.toArray();

    return sortedArray;
}

}
```

....

```
public class SortingArrayTestt {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double[] array = { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };

    Double[] sortingArray = SortingArray.sortItOut(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortingArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(sortingArray[i]);
    }

}

}
```

...

The console output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.fatih.sortarray.SortingArray.sortItOut(SortingArray.java:25)
at com.fatih.sortarray.SortingArrayTestt.main(SortingArrayTestt.java:9)
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

All of the array you are initializing are of size 0. initialize the arrays like following.

```
Double[] sortedArray = new Double[array.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand array initializers (example like `{1, 2, 3, 4}`) automatically calculate the size of the array depending upon the elements that you have placed, but you did not place any elements in `arrayOdd`, `arrayEven` arrays, so it will be of zero size.

In short, you have created **`arrayOdd`, `arrayEven` arrays with zero size** and you are trying place/access the array elements(of that 0 sized array) which is causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so you need to create the array with size as shown below:

```
Double[] arrayOdd = new Double[array.length];
Double[] arrayEven = new Double[array.length];
Double[] sortedArray = new Double[array.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] array = { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };

    List sortingArray = SortingArray.sortItOut(array);

    for (Object item : sortingArray) {
        System.out.print(item);
    }
 }
```

}

```
class SortingArray {

public static List sortItOut(Double[] array) {

    ArrayList<Double> arrayOdd = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> arrayEven = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> sortedArray = new ArrayList<>();


    for(Double item : array){
        if(item % 2 == 0){
            arrayOdd.add(item);
        }else{
            arrayEven.add(item);
        }
    }



    Arrays.sort(new ArrayList[]{arrayOdd}, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(new ArrayList[]{arrayEven});

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrayOdd));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayEven));
    sortedArray = list;

    return sortedArray;
}
```

}